# VBA Word - Move cursor to a new line beyond the border

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am trying to move cursor to a new line in the Word document that I generate from Excel using VBA.

I do manage to add a new line, however since the last text entry in the Word document has top and bottom borders, every new line added stays within those borders. Is there a way to leave that box and go beyond the border?

Code is attached. Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateWordDocument()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdSelection As Object
Dim wdTable As Object
Dim wdRange As Object

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wdApp.Visible = True

Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
Set wdSelection = wdApp.Selection
With wdSelection
    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
    .Font.Size = "26"
    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .TypeText Text:=("TEXT 1")
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    .TypeParagraph

    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
    .Font.Size = "11"
    .Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    .TypeText ("Text 2")
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
    .TypeParagraph
    .TypeParagraph

    .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
    .Font.Size = "11"
    .Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
    .TypeText ("Text 3")
        With .ParagraphFormat
            .Alignment = 1
            .Borders(-1).LineStyle = 1
            .Borders(-1).LineWidth = 2
            .Borders(-3).LineStyle = 1
            .Borders(-3).LineWidth = 2
        End With
    .TypeParagraph ' !!! This line must be modified
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very elegant, but you could defer the borders until later:

```
Sub CreateWordDocument()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdSelection As Object
    Dim wdTable As Object
    Dim wdRange As Object

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True

    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
    Set wdSelection = wdApp.Selection
    With wdSelection
        .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
        .Font.Size = "26"
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .TypeText Text:=("TEXT 1")
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        .TypeParagraph

        .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
        .Font.Size = "11"
        .Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
        .TypeText ("Text 2")
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        .TypeParagraph
        .TypeParagraph

        .Font.Name = "Calibri Light"
        .Font.Size = "11"
        .Font.Color = RGB(128, 128, 128)
        .TypeText ("Text 3")
        .TypeParagraph ' !!! This line must be modified
    End With

    With wdDoc.Paragraphs(4)
        With .Format
            .Alignment = 1
            .Borders(-1).LineStyle = 1
            .Borders(-1).LineWidth = 2
            .Borders(-3).LineStyle = 1
            .Borders(-3).LineWidth = 2
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it might be not very elegant but it does exactly what it is supposed to do, thank you very much for that, I really appreaciate your help!